# Configurar POST, para obtener hash y guardar en localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

Enviar User Agent en el body y obtener un identificador o hash cada vez que se ingresa a la pagina guardar el valor del hash en el localstorage.

debo hacer una petición a una url de ejemplo (no tiene que existir, lo importante es la
implementación en JavaScript) por POST, y debe pasarle en el body del request el User Agent, si
se accedió con el navegador en modo incógnito, el referer y su fingerprint.
Estos parámetros tienen que ser obtenidos con JavaScript antes de hacer la petición.
Para el caso del fingerprint, la idea es que cada usuario que ingrese a la page obtenga un hash
único para identificarlo, y se mantenga en sus siguientes visitas. Usar cualquier fuente de
almacenamiento disponible desde el navegador para persistir el mismo.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

export const Api = () => {

    const [postId, setPostId] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        // POST request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                title: 'User Agent Hash identificador',
                 
            })
        };
        fetch('https://urldemo/posts', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setPostId(data.id));
           
    }, [postId]);
    return (
        <div>
            ID: {postId}
        </div>
    )
}
```